# String to Date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Is there a way to quickly convert this date format to DATE in SQL?

```
{ “date_from”:”22112017”,”date_to”:”22112017”}
```

This is needed to filter the data between these dates

(There are a lot of conversion entries on the web, but I haven't found that format)

EDIT:

```
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = CONVERT(VARCHAR, '22112017', 103)
PRINT @EndDate
```

`Error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

WHAT I HAVE:

```
@StartDate = '22112017'
@EndDate = '22112020'
```

WHAT I NEED TO DO:

```
SELECT * from tblMy WHERE ReceivedDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

Comment: What is your SQl Server vesrion?

Comment: @Zhorov SQL Server 2016

Comment: Is that actually the value of your string? What version of SQL Server? That looks liek JSON, however, with stylised double quotes (`”` insteadd of `"`). If you can fix the above so that the quotes aren't stylised, and you're using a recent enough version of SQL Server, you can parse the above as JSON.

Comment: @Larnu Don't look at it. It's just a JSON with dates (I wanted to show what format the date is in)

Comment: You need to convert '22112017' into date ?

Comment: What do you mean *"don't look at it"*(? If I can't look at your sample data, then what *does* your data look like..?

Answer (score 3):

If you fix your JSON to not use stylised double quotes (`”`) and use standard ones (`"`) then you can parse this as JSON. Once you extract the values, you can inject a couple of `/` characters in and then convert to a `date` with the style code 103 (`dd/MM/yyyy`):

```sql
DECLARE @String nvarchar(MAX) = N'{ "date_from":"22112017","date_to":"22112017"}';

SELECT CONVERT(date,STUFF(STUFF(OJ.date_from,5,0,'/'),3,0,'/'),103) AS date_from,
       CONVERT(date,STUFF(STUFF(OJ.date_to,5,0,'/'),3,0,'/'),103) AS date_to
FROM (VALUES(@String))V(S)
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(V.S)
     WITH (date_from varchar(8),
           date_to varchar(8)) OJ;
```

---

Edit:

Seems the OP has moved their goal posts, this has nothing to do with JSON.

The problem here is your literal strings. When using literal strings for a date and time data type use either `yyyyMMdd` or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn` as they are both unambiguous regardless of language and data type:

```sql
DECLARE @StartDate date,
        @EndDate date;

SET @StartDate = '20171222';
SET @EndDAte = '20201122';

SELECT *
FROM tblMy
WHERE ReceivedDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the error "Error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

```
DECLARE @EndDate VARCHAR(MAX) = '22112017'
DECLARE @datevar date = CAST(SUBSTRING(@EndDate, 3, 2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(@EndDate, 
1, 2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(@EndDate, 5, 4) AS date);  
SELECT @datevar;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest converting the value to a standard SQL Server date value.  This is pretty simple:

```
select convert(date, left(val, 4) + substring(val, 3, 2) + right(val, 2))
```

The standard date format is YYYYMMDD.  Yours is DDMMYYYY, so string operations can convert it to the correct format.  Of course, what you should probably do is to convert the value to a date in the application layer and pass the date value in as a parameter.